# LibreOffice icon tips shows incomplete text/info

Tags: libreoffice

I have LibreOffice 5, and since I installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, LibreOffice's icons tips show it's text/info incomplete.

I can't find a way to fix it.

I've tried:
Tools > Options > Libre Office > View

There I turn on/off the "Screen font anti-aliasing", fixing it temporarily, but after closing LibreOffice the problem returns.

Any idea of how to fix it definitely?

Image of the problem:

[image]

Comment: Can you edit your question to mention the exact version? I'm on `Version: 5.1.3.2` and I see what you see.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible we are hit by [Bug 91533 - Tooltips are truncated if OS default font is size 12](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=91533).

To quote from there:

> Tested under Ubuntu / Unity 15.04 with several different default fonts (Ubuntu,
>   Sans, Linux Biolinum, etc.) at OS level. It is clearer with the tooltips of the
>   status bar.
>   If I change the size of the default font to 11, there is no problem.

And a [subsequent comment](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=91533#c6) in the bug thread has this:

> Note: Today I installed my own build of LO 5.0 beta1+ on another computer with
>   bigger screen. This computer is under Ubuntu 15.04 x86-64 too and I can't
>   reproduce the problem with it. So the problem seems to be related to the screen
>   size. On my laptop with screen 1366x768 I have the problem, on a screen
>   1920x1080 I do not reproduce it.

According to [comment #14](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=91533#c14) dated 2016-09-08, a fix has been pushed and will be available in version 5.1.6.